# Word check Global template add-ins using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a global template in the startup folder. Most of time the GlobalAddin.dotm is checked but once a while it's not checked (see image). How do I make sure this checkbox is always checked?

[image: Templates and Add-ins dialog box]

Comment: Look at the properties and methods for the `Application.Addins` collection and the `Addin` object. It's possible to test whether an add-in is loaded, to install it, to unload...

Comment: Do you know the reason why sometimes it will be unchecked? Would GlobalAddin.dotm placed in network cause the problem?

Comment: It's hard to say... If there's a network connection problem, then a network location could be a reason- if Word can't load the template when it starts, for example. Other software explicitly unloading add-ins would be another possibility.

Comment: Where is the best place to place the code you mentioned above to make sure the addins will be loaded?